# Android getting external storage Absolute Path

Tags: android, storage

I want to download some files and save them into the internal storage of the phone/tab. Tried on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 and Galaxt Tab 10.1. When I use `/storage/sdcard0/` on them the code runs successfully but when I use `Galaxy Nexus 3` the code fails.

I want to get absolute path of the phoe or tab's internal storage' `Absolute Path`.

Does it possible, if so how?

Comment: This question is quite confused between internal/external, so **please never propose it as a duplicate for anything**.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> When I use /storage/sdcard0/ on them the code runs successfully but when I use Galaxy Nexus 3 the code fails.

`/storage/sdcard0/` is not internal storage. It is external storage.

(BTW, since there is no device named "Galaxy Nexus 3", I am assuming that you simply meant "Galaxy Nexus")

To find locations on *internal* storage for your app, use `getFilesDir()`, called on any `Context` (such as your `Activity`, to get a `File` object.

To get a location on *external* storage unique for your app, use `getExternalFilesDir()`, called on any `Context` (such as your `Activity`, to get a `File` object.

To get a *standard* location on *external* storage for common types of files (e.g., movies), use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` on `Environment`.

To get the *root* of *external* storage, use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` on `Environment`. This, however, is considered sloppy programming nowadays, as it encourages developers to just put files in random locations.

Comment: I'm new on android programming. I save files into the storage. For example when I look at on my Galaxy Note 2's /storage/sdcard0/ I see Whatssapp, Music, Alarm sth.. How can I get /storage/sdcard0/ path for all phones/tabs. Thanks.

Comment: @ErdinçÖzdemir: use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` on `Environment`. This, however, is considered sloppy programming nowadays, as it encourages developers to just put files in random locations. Also, the *specific* path that represents external storage varies by manufacturer and OS version. That's why you use methods, rather than hard-coded strings, to find locations on external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have internal storage on my LG optimus device and it points internal storage to **/storage/sdcard0/**, i checked it through file manager....so it bit confusing whether sdcard0 point to internal or external

Comment: @shihon: "I have internal storage on my LG optimus device" -- you have internal and external storage on an LG Optimius, unless you broke it with a hammer or something, in which case you have neither. Please read the documentation for what the definition is of "external storage".

Comment: @CommonsWare: Why should i broke my device with a hammer...i know definition of external storage,...anyway thanks for you hammer support

Answer (score 10):

why can't you use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for getting `/storage/sdcard0/` path from code ?

need to add permissions as well

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution found is 
1st edit the emulator:

1. Go to Android Virtual Device Manager and then edit the emulator
2. Set say 100 MB for SD d card for the respected emulator, say Ok
3. Save and close emulator and start

It worked for me, the app is no longer giving an error and is working fine.