# Reading excel xlsx file in internal storage using Apache Poi

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I want to read an xlsx file in internal storage (not sdcard but the app's internal) using apache poi. Since I have the file I would prefer if I didn't use an input stream but rather load the file directly into Apache Poi. How do I do this? Thanks. Keyword here is 'internal storage'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new `Workbook`, you can use either a `File` or an `InputStream`:

```
// Use a file
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("MyExcel.xls"));

// Use an InputStream, needs more memory
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("MyExcel.xlsx"));
```

More details are available on the [POI site](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream).

Comment: Thanks! I want to use the file. Is this file retrieved from internal storage automatically? Example: The above code will retrieve the file called MyExcel.xlsx which is in internal storage?

Comment: I have no idea how your directory structure is setup, but instead of using MyExcel.xlsx, you'll have to point that to wherever your file is located.  This post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17546843/697281 looks to have some good information regarding locating the internal storage.