# Use phone internal memory Android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I want to read a file from the phone internal memory.I have two memory in my device that is sdcard0 and sdcard1.sdcard1 is phone internal memory.So my file is in the phone internal memory .
It's path is `/storage/sdcard1/Android/New_Data.xml`.So is this right way to access or not 
Please suggest me what i have do for this

Code

```
File file=new File("/storage/sdcard1/Android/New_Data.xml");
        if (file.exists()) {

        }else{

        }
```

This is working fine but i want to know is this a right way or not

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal. check this for internal storage

Comment: @Raghunandan /storage/sdcard0/Android/New_Data.xml this path it is returning me

Comment: pls look at the storage options both internal and external storage http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this might help you '

Read from here [LINK TO UNDERSTAND](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());

fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access Android storage is

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

In your case, this would return `/storage/sdcard1`, and you could code

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"Android/New_Data.xml";
```

to get the pathname.

See [the Environment reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29).

Comment: how will access please help me with complete path

Comment: @PoojaDubey looks like you have a file on your external storage. try this  `File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.seperator+Android+File.seperator+New_Data.xml)` If its on external storage add permission in manifest.

Comment: after what you said it is showing me R cannot be resolved to a variable error what i have to do now

Comment: Suggest you post a new question with the details for the XML error.

Comment: /storage/sdcard0/Android/New_Data.xml this path it is returning me but the i need /storage/sdcard1/Android/New_Data.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try getDir().

Refer [Android getting external storage Absolute Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546718/android-getting-internal-storage-absolute-path)

```
File getdirectory = context.getDir("Samplefolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
if(!getdirectory .exists)
{
     getdirectory .mkdirs();
}
```