# How to get file path of file from internal storage in android

Tags: android

In our application we are storing pdf files into internal storage.Now i want to get its filepath and need to store into DB. Please tell me how to get its file path. 
below code:

```
public void storeIntoInternalMem(byte[] databytes, String name) {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = openFileOutput(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOuputStream.write(databytes);
            fileOuputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546718/android-getting-internal-storage-absolute-path


refer this links......

Answer (score 32):

you can use `Context.getFilesDir()` method to get the path to the internal storage

**Edit**

when using this line `FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = openFileOutput(name, MODE_PRIVATE);` the internal storage path is obtained by the default implementation of the `openFileOutput()` method. A new file is created at that location with the specified name. Now when you want to get the path of the same file, you can use the `getFilesDir()` to get the absolute path to the directory where the file was created. You can do something like this :-

`File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + name);`

Comment: can you please answer it briefly?

Comment: where it can be found in my mobile phone

Answer (score 12):

`String dir = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();`

Answer (score 0):

```
 getFileStreamPath(String name) of Context.
```

Returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a file created with

```
openFileOutput(String, int)
```

is stored.

Answer (score 0):

On kotlin:

"$filesDir/image.png"