# read and write from Internal storage

Tags: java, android, file-io

I am having this exception when trying to read from the file

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/.../files

I used this method because it can handle Unicode text while reading from the file

```
public void save(String string )
{

String filename = "main";


FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public String read()
{
    try
    {

        Reader readerUnicode =
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(getFilesDir()), Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
                int e = 0;
                String f="";
                while ((e = readerUnicode.read()) != -1) {
                // cast to char. The casting removes the left most bit.
                 f = f+Character.toString((char) e);
                System.out.print(f);
                }

                return f;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

        return e+"";
    }

}
```

how can I retrieve the internal  save path

thanks

Comment: can you illustrate more plz

Comment: I have, see my answer below :)

Comment: @Doomsknight - no, this is not a duplicate.  And the target of your link is a horribly confused question anyway, where the poster says "internal" but actually means "external".

Comment: @ChrisStratton I noticed the variation, it was linked from this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280250/how-to-get-file-path-of-file-from-internal-storage-in-android?lq=1  Which does seem similar. They all have good ideas of what might be the issue. I am unsure of if the `MODE_PRIVATE` is an issue. Im happy to see the solution from anyone, although im sure he was missing the file name at the least.

Comment: @Doomsknight - one does not propose a duplicate when something merely has "good ideas of what *might* be the issue".  Duplicates are for when the problem (or at least the solution) is **known for a fact** to be the same.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ive removed it, but its still a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280250/how-to-get-file-path-of-file-from-internal-storage-in-android?lq=1 . Either way, thats why it requires more than just one vote to close. Incase people get it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `getFilesDir()` But not setting the actual file name. Just the directory path.

Try adding the file name in. Plus, you should probably add an extension like  `.txt` to both the save and load path.

```
 new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(getFilesDir() + "/" + filename ), Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
```

and change `filename` to something more sensible.

```
String filename = "main.txt";
```

You could/should also check the file exists before accessing it. (Although you do try catch anyway)

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + filename);
if(!file.exists()) 
   return "";
```

Comment: same error java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/asia.tv/files/main: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) where asia.tv is the name of my main package but I am calling it from different package named news

Comment: @user3027345 Try the variation that sets the extension. Are you sure the file actually exists?...  Have you called `save()` at any point before loading

Comment: I did the save as shown in my main code above but i used this code:                                                         try{
          FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("main");
          int c;
          String temp="";
          while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
             temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
          }
        return temp;


       }catch(Exception e){
        return "no";
       }
       and it worked but my main problem was with unicode reading .... but anyway i didn't know where does it save the data

Comment: @user3027345 Yes, `openFileInput` prepends the folder location for you. You need to use `getFilesDir` when using `FileInputStream`.