# How to read files and folders in a specific directory on android

Tags: android, io

I am trying to read all files and folders in a directory specified by the user.

I use:

```
File file = new File("/");
String[] files = file.list();
```

This works and gives me a list of the file names and folders in the root directory.
This works fine, but when I specify anything other then "/" it crashes.

How do I fix this, am I not giving it a valid path or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Post the stack trace from the crash.

Comment: what do you mean by anything other than `/` ? Also before getting the list please check if the file exists.

Comment: Sorry but I have never gotten an emulator to work so I run the program straight on my phone and it doesn't give any crash report.

Comment: I'm not specifying a file or atleast I shouldn't as far as i understand. I have tried other paths like "/storage", "storage/", "/storage/", etc as many as I could think of(storage

Comment: "and it doesn't give any crash report." - It does. Look at LogCat in Eclipse.

Comment: I am not running it on an emulator I run it on my phone. If you mean that a crash report is stored on the phone and that you can look at it from eclipse, how?

Comment: use DDMS, you will see your phone there and also your logcat from phone.

Comment: Also in DDMS you can see your file structure, so you can understand which folder exists and which don't.

Comment: @gumba: The Logcat tab in your IDE should show the errors you've encountered. If not (which is unlikely), you can view error log using an app called [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en) available from Google Play. Install this free app into your device and post your app's error log from Catlog back here. Without error log, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` is the root of android and there exists not folder name **storage**, so when you are using

`String[] files = file.list();`

you are asking android to give the list of files inside **storage** which doesn't even exists. Thus, you are getting errors.

Best practice is to assume that the folder might not exist, even if you are sure it will eg user can delete a folder that you created on the SDCard which will cause crashes in your apps. So use the following code

```
if(file.exists()){
String [] filenames = file.list();
}
```

And this is just my guess but i think you are searching for SDCard, if so then use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

with permission to read SDCard files.

**Update :-**
For reading files in internal and external memory please see the following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546843/1979347

Comment: I just chose storage for testing and I know it exists on my phone. Now I am just trying to read all files and folder somewhere other then "/".

Comment: Where exactly is **storage**, I think you are referring path incorrectly.

Comment: If I read from "/" it is in there, if i specify "/" it works as it should but anything other just crash. I think it should be just /storage but that doesn't work.

Comment: I really don't think that **storage** will be in `/`. Please use my `if ` loop to check if the file exists since  `/storage` is correct. You can't make a directory in the root folder unless you have root permissions and have used a root explorer app to make the folder. If you have both, then the folder can be there else not.

Comment: I dont recal giving any permission but I have an app on which I have seen that storage exists. Do you know the permission code?

Comment: You can' get root access using permission. Google it you will see. Since you don't know about root I am 100% confident that **/storage** isn't in your root path. Is **storage** in your SDCard ?

Comment: When I use the app to see the files ans folders I go back as far as I can, there I see storage. If I use "/" I get to the same place. I dont know what it is stored on but in storage are one folder called "sdcard0" and one called "usbdisk" which I think are sdcard and the internal storage but I am not sure.

Comment: I just want to ask you one question. Is it a new phone or you bought it from someone? If it is new, and you never rooted it then there is no way that it is rooted. Some of the folders on `/` are acct, cache, config, data, etc. Do you see anyone of those?

Comment: It is a new phone and I have not rooted it. And yes I do see acct, cache, config, etc. If i use the app I see those and when I use / on my app I see those. My app works when I enter / but when I try to add some of the folders which I can see when I enter / it crashes.

Comment: I tried some other files in / and they work but some still doesn't, for examples /system works but /storage doesn't???

Comment: If you can see the directories of some apps but not of storage then I really don't know what's wrong. I think you should mark this question solved and ask a new question.